# Where to trigger load from PlayerPrefs for data in a static class?

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

I have this save system that saves screenshots in consecutively-numbered files. I store the number of the last number used in `PlayerPrefs`, so that the next save continues from there.

But I'm not sure where to call the `LoadNumber` method to load the last used number, since this is a static class with no `Start()` function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public static class SaveSystem
{
    private static int countName;

    public static string Load(string FileName)
    {
        string content = File.ReadAllText(FileName);

        return content;
    }

    private static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/Saved Games/SaveSlot{1} SavedGameSlot_{2}x{3}_{4}/SavedGameSlot_{1}x{2}_{3}.png",
            Application.persistentDataPath,
            countName,
            width, height, System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
    }

    public static void Save(string saveString, int resWidth, int resHeight)
    {
        string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
        string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(filename);
        string fileName = Path.Combine(directory, "savegame.txt");
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, saveString);

        countName++;

        SaveNumber();
    }

    public static void SaveNumber()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("countName", countName);
    }

    public static void LoadNumber()
    {
        countName = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("countName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read PlayerPrefs lazily, the first time someone tries to read the current count:

```
static int? _count;

public int count {
    get {
        if (!_count.HasValue) {
            _count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("countName", 0);
        }
        return _count.Value;
    }
    set {
        _count = value;
    }
}
```

Or you can read it eagerly as the game boots up, after all scripts in your starting scene have gotten their `Awake()` message, using the [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html):

```
[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
static void LoadNumber()
{
    countName = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("countName", 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be simple like this,

```
public static int CountName
{
    get => PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("countName", defaultValue);
    set => PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("countName", value);
}
```

This is as simple as like changing normal variable value.

Comment: This will work, but be slightly more expensive for variables you use frequently, since it will take the slow path of looking up into `PlayerPrefs` with a string key every time. The version I showed keeps a local cache of the variable, so the slow path only needs to be taken for the initial load, and when you initiate a save.